# Android Calling Async task inside another Async task?

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous

I'm trying to do an Async call inside of another Async method I am not sure if I'm doing this correctly, or if it's even possible. First call gets the partID's from the database, and then second gets the lotNumbers of the part's. My reasoning for doing this is to be able to loop through and put the associated partLotNumebrs inside a Spinner and display a list of Spinners in a Listview. what am I doing wrong? Is this even possible? I know you can't make HTTP calls inside the main so I'm not sure of any other way to do this.

the error I'm getting.

```
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at com.cbs.iomamobile.ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity$getPartLotNumbers.onPostExecute(ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.java:258)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at com.cbs.iomamobile.ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity$getPartLotNumbers.onPostExecute(ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.java:1)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-13 11:04:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it's pointing to this line

```
textView.setText(temp.getString("name"));
```

it seems neither my Spinner or textView are valid, no idea why.

assembly.class

```
public class ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity extends ListActivity{
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String productName;
    String olid;
    String assemblyName;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // url to get all orders list
    private static String url_get_assembly_parts = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_assembly_parts.php";

    // url to get all orders list
    private static String url_get_part_partlotnumbers = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_part_partLotNumbers.php";



    // orders JSONArray
    JSONArray assembly = null;
    JSONArray parts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_assemblies);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        assemblyName = i.getStringExtra("assemblyName");
        olid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_OLID);

        Log.d("assemblyName", "" + assemblyName);

        // Loading orders in Background Thread
        new LoadAllAssemblyParts().execute();



    }

    // Response from Edit Order Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all assemblyparts by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllAssemblyParts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        /**
         * getting All orders from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assemblyName", assemblyName));   

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_assembly_parts, "GET", params);

            // Check log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All partID's: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // orders found
                    // Getting Array of Parts
                    assembly = json.getJSONArray("assembly");

                    // looping through All Parts
                    for (int i = 0; i < assembly.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = assembly.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString("partID");
                        String name = c.getString("assemblyName");

                        new getPartLotNumbers().execute(id);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no part ID's found

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all orders
        }

    }

    class getPartLotNumbers extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray>{

        Spinner spinner;
        TextView textView;

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {            

            JSONArray parts = null;
            int success;
            String partID = args[0];

            try{
                // Building Parameters 
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("partID", partID));

                // getting part Lot Numbers by making HTTP request
                // Note that part Lot Numbers will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_part_partlotnumbers, "GET", params);

                // check log for json response
                Log.d("List of PartID's", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if(success == 1){

                    // successfully received part Lot Numbers
                    parts = json.getJSONArray("parts"); // JSON Array

                }else{
                    // part Lot Numbers not not found
                }

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //return array of part Lot Numbers
            return parts;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray products){
            //spinner and textview
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.LotNumbers);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.partName);

            //list of partLotNumbers
            List<String> partLotNumberList = new ArrayList<String>();

            //move list from JSON to List
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<products.length();i++){
                    JSONObject temp = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    partLotNumberList.add(temp.getString("partLotNumber"));
            }

            //get Part Name
            JSONObject temp = products.getJSONObject(0);
            textView.setText(temp.getString("name"));

            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //adapter for Spinner           
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partLotNumberList);           
            adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            //set the adapter to the spinnner
            spinner.setAdapter(adp1);                       
        }

    }
}
```

all_assembly_parts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

view_assembly_parts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/partName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/LotNumbers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're better off keeping things simple and using one AsyncTask.  You can perform multiple network requests within the same doInBackground method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will address the crash first.

You have a ListActivity which contains only the list. I am guessing the two layout files you posted are custom cell that are used to display the information. In the AsyncTask, when you call findViewById() it is looking in the activity's layout (which only contains the list view) and not each cell's layout. This is why you are getting both of them as null since there is no such items in the activity. If you want to update the information in the cell, then this is not the way to do it.

You need to look into custom cells, list view. Google for a simple example.

Hope this helps understand the crash.